# How to call JavaScript from ChromeWebDriver and InternetExplorerWebDriver when the target is in an IFrame

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Selenium 2b1 and getting good results driving Firefox (both MacOS & Windows). We would like to run the same tests against IE and Chrome. After adding a couple of workarounds for ChromeDriver, I find that both ChromeDriver and InternetExplorerDriver fail in executeScript(), even if the script is 'return "Hello!"', after driver.switchTo().frame(canvasName). ChromeDriver reports "Was not on a page, so could not execute javascript" while InternetExplorerDriver reports "JavaScript error".

Here's the Groovy code:

```
selenium.switchTo().frame(canvasName)

log.info("Canvas open.  Waiting for Game to load.");
waitFor(selenium, 30) {
    selenium.findElement(By.id("Game")).click()
}

waitFor(selenium, 30) {
    def eval = null
    try {
        eval = selenium.executeScript("return document.URL")
        log.fine("executeScript returns [$eval]")
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.fine("Exception from executeScript: $e.message")
    }
    return eval
}
```

The variable, selenium, has in instance of RemoteWebDriver. The waitFor method creates an instance of WebDriverWait and passes a wrapper instance referencing the closure parameter as the until parameter.  Note that the element with id 'Game' only exists in the IFrame that has been selected by the first statement in the code above.

Hope someone out there has experience with this!

Comment: Now that [Se2b2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-2.0b2.zip&can=2&q=) is released, it's pretty clear that the (remaining) problem is with ChromeDriver: with the new release, InternetExplorerDriver works like magic with the same test!

If you have an idea how to get a later ChromeDriver than what's in 2b2, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the limitations in the InternetExplorerDriver and ChromeDriver versions in Selenium 2.0b1. The Selenium 2.0b2 release includes an improved InternetExplorerDriver that supports switching to the IFrame and running JavaScript against its DOM. A more robust ChromeDriver is still to come. Unfortunately, the [Beta 2 announcement](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/selenium-2-0b2-released/) makes no mention of plans for ChromeDriver (or the possibility of support for Safari).